# Error in scene in Java FX

Tags: javafx-8

I'm new to javaFX 8 and working with a simple project, but im having some issues with scene.

I get this error:

```
Error:(35, 25) java: method getScene in class javafx.stage.Window cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: javafx.scene.Scene
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

And this is the code:

```
package ch.makery.address;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class MainApp extends Application{

    private Stage primaryStage;
    private BorderPane rootLayout;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        this.primaryStage.setTitle("AddressApp");

        initRootLayout();

        showPersonOverview();
    }

    public void initRootLayout() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
            rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();

            Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
            primaryStage.getScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void showPersonOverview() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view.Personview.fxml"));
            AnchorPane personOverview = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

            rootLayout.setCenter(personOverview);
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
        return primaryStage;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should be `setScene` not `getScene`. ***G***etters usually don't take parameters. The compilation error is pretty clear about this: `actual and formal argument lists differ in length`